# Adding a radio buttons in views exposed filters for published and unpublished drupal 7

Tags: hooks, views

[image: a view with content type as select list]

The above view shows articles content type, which is exposed filter.I want to add a radio buttons as i have shown in image for published and unpublished,can I get this functionality programmaticaly and how

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module. If you need to do this programmaticaly then you may need to look at the code of this module. You need to implement the hook_theme as done in better_exposed_filters.module and implement the code to display as radio button as done in better_exposed_filters.theme(Function: theme_select_as_radios)

I would suggest using the module directly if that is an option.

Comment: Agree. This module will let you change the Selector Yes/No which exposed filters will give you by default for Content: Published filter. If that is what you are needing (which is what your graphic suggests) then it could be a useful solution

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations):

> This module augments Views by allowing bulk operations to be executed
>   on the displayed rows. It does so by showing a checkbox in front of
>   each node, and adding a select box containing operations that can be
>   applied. Drupal Core or Rules actions can be used.

Even if it can't do exactly what you want, you could modify it into a custom module that could.  Gives a good starting point for the code.